# jQuery Mobile 1.4 JavaScript Page Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, transition

Is anyone familiar with how to create custom JavaScript based page transitions in jQuery Mobile 1.4? It looks like as of 1.4 they really changed the way transitions are done. I can't find any examples through searches or their website. If you have successfully got one to work, please explain how or post some code.